# Why can't I install Ubuntu-Sdk

Tags: software-installation

I am not able to install the Ubuntu Sdk on my pc.
I get this error in terminal:

```
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-sdk
```

How could I overcome this issue?

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using? Did you try `sudo apt-get update` before installing the software?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/get-the-sdk/  :

> For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 12.10, 13.04 and 13.10 users:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
> ```
>
> Alternatively, for those using a development release:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
> ```